# Android LinearLayout, set background to Transparent

Tags: java, android, xml

I am inflating a `bottom_sheet_layout`. It contains a LinearLayout as the root element. It has one child CardView.

I've tried the following:

```
setting `android:background` property to 
    1. #00FFFFFF
    2. #00000000
    3. @android:color/transparent

setting the background color of LinearLayout programatically

    `LinearLayout l = container.findViewById(R.id.root_element);
     l.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
```

This is the `BottomSheet.Class` that is linked to the `bottom_sheet_layout`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);
LinearLayout l = container.findViewById(R.id.root_element);
l.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
return v;
}
```

This is the full `bottom_sheet_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_element"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/poiName"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:text="@string/poiName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <!--Location-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans_medium"
            android:text="@string/ui_location"
            android:textFontWeight="800" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/work_sans"
            android:text="@string/ui_location_addr" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/share"
        android:scaleType="center"
        card_view:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the `Map Fragment`. Here is where I inflate the `bottom_sheet_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Following several guides, I still could not get the `#00FFFFFF` method to work. Programmatically setting the color to transparent, crashes the application.

It seems that in earlier questions on StackOverflow, setting the background to the hex code with alpha value used to work. Now I only get a dim gray background.

Screenshots of the application

1. [Image Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXUKz.png)
2. [App ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q8qH.jpg)

Comment: Share me your xml layout file bottom_sheet_layout.xml

Comment: please add layout's xml file

Comment: Edit: the XML Layout has been added to the question

Comment: why don't you just remove the LL if it's only a transparent container that does nothing

Comment: But, then the CardView extends to full width automatically, and I can't even see the borders of the card. It just becomes a plain Modal Bottom Sheet. The LinearLayout helps to atleast maintain the shape of the card.

Comment: Is this layout loaded into a `<Fragment>' from another layout? If yes, please share this other xml layout.

Comment: I have 3 XML sheets, 
1. MainActivity (Does Nothing)
2. MapsActivity (Fragment that loads google maps)
3. BottomSheetActivity (The XML code is posted in the question)

I am only inflating the bottomsheet in maps activity.

Comment: So, what do you want to see in the background of `bottom_sheet_layout`? The Google maps? If, yes, then share your MapsActivity xml layout.

Comment: Sure! Please see the update

Comment: And where is your `MapView` object? Programmatically?

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to where could I find `MapView` Object?

Comment: Please, put @Ferran in front of your message, otherwise, I'll not be informed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `MapView`, I supposed that you are inflating the Google Map + `bottom_sheet_layout` in the same fragment. If Yes, I think that your issue is not the LinearLayout transparency but you are inserting `bottom_sheet_layout` to the bottom of the fragment container, not over the map.

You can use this layout for your Map fragment
(androidx, but very similar if you are using android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- use this fragment for your google map -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <!-- use this fragment for your bottom_sheet class -->    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"            // with this you do not need the LinearLayout root_element 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then, you can play with your `CardView` (or `LinearLayout`) `visibility` to show the card or not.

Other layouts are possible like using directly the card view instead of a `Fragment`.

Comment: Yes, I did realize that the Bottom Sheet Activity was the culprit of that solid background, after long hours of frustration. However I modified your answer by a little. I used `<include>` tag get my `bottom_sheet_layout` and then added a `BottomSheetBehaviour` to it.

Comment: @vDevel_00 Great. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you with some sort of solutions, which you can also try and see if that works or not.

1. Make use of **alpha property in your .java** file

Range the value as per your ease

```
LinearLayout l = container.findViewById(R.id.root_element);
l.setAlpha(0.4);
```

2. You can make use of alpha in your XML file too:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/l1"
  android:alpha="0.5"
  android:layout_width="190dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

0.0 is for fully transparent and 1.0 is for fully opaque.

Let me know if any of the solutions work for you. However, do more research here, you will definitely get a solution. Happy coding.

Comment: This did not work, as I am setting an alpha to the root element LInearLayout. Using your solution makes the child elements lighter, almost like the child elements are inheriting the alpha property from the parent.

Comment: Please have a look at this image [here](https://gyazo.com/2c8ba035665c6218e78b4886c04f567c)
This is the result when I set the value of alpha programatically or through xml.
And this [here](https://gyazo.com/6f14dc88d5643cfb63d795691b2e7ed9)
This is the result with no alpha set.

Answer (score 0):

Try background null.

```
<LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@null">

        ......

      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although, that did not work.

Comment: Actually this worked, but I couldn't figure out why until I realized that my BottomSheetActivity was the one with a solid background, where I was inflating my `bottom_sheet_layout`. I followed @Ferran 's solution in combination with your solution.

Comment: @vDevel_00 : Great , Go ahead +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the child layout elements doesn't have backgrounds?

Comment: Yes. None of the child layouts have any background property